# angular-ui-route with IE8

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use angular-ui-router in my current project - and it was all fine in chrome & firefox. But when it comes to trying it out in IE8, it doesnt seem to work. I'm getting the error 'TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or methodundefined'.

I initially thought that I must have done something wrong, so I tried the sample app that is linked from the angular-ui-router page: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/. But this sample app doesnt seem to work either (with the same error message).

So my question is... is IE8 supported? Or do I have to use angular-router? I would really love to use ui-router (for nested partials, multiple partials per page .. ) :(

Thanks!

Regards,

Alex

Answer (score 4):

Ok. Angular-ui-router doesnt seem to be supported on IE8 by default, as there's a lot of Javascript incompatibility. After including [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim), it all works fine.

Comment: We've only had one IE8 compatibility issue reported and it was resolved some time ago. If you have an issue, please report it.